# What s the official gui developped by the Ethereum fundation? Does it allows to display erc20 tokens?

Tags: go-ethereum, erc-20, history, gui, archive-node

After losing access to my email address, I am asked by an exchange to show the deposit history for a specific coin (in that case an erc20 running on Ethereum) from a specific address (which I own the private key) used to fund my account on the exchange in order to be able to withdraw the money.

But when I sent them screenshots from a block explorer and an other one Metamask, they refused it, stating it wasn t a proof I was owning the address. They asked the screenshot to come from my own node client running the official node software (which I suppose means geth since Aleth doesn t support archive node mode).

Since it s an erc20 token, getting the deposit history involve accessing previous states from the contract. So after purschasing an expensive workstation powerfull enough in order to run my own full geth archival node, I m still having questions.
**Does geth still feature a built in gui or a cli able to display the deposit history from a command line?** If not which is the new projet resulting of the split of those functionnalities?

Comment: The Ethereum Foundation doesn't develop anything, it only defines standards.

Comment: @goodvibration don t know how to call it, I was reffering to this https://github.com/ethereum.

Comment: If you just need proof that you have access to an address, the easiest way is to [sign a message](https://support.mycrypto.com/how-to/getting-started/how-to-sign-and-verify-messages-on-ethereum). The exchange can verify that message to confirm that you signed it.

Comment: @Morten, I tried that, but they ignore it. In addition to id verification with selfie and proof of address they want a picture using the ui developped by the organization managing https://github.com/ethereum.